# Rails loop with with image_tag and associated image from assets folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looping through the model which contains the images. In the first part of the loop I'm showing only the first image if an image exists. This works fine!

The second part of the loop I would like to pick up the ones that doesn't  have an image and show an image from the assets folder.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
<% @items.each do |item|%>
<% item.attachments[0...1].each do |attachment| %>
              <%= image_tag attachment.image.url(:mini) unless attachment.image.present? %>
              <%= image_tag attachment.image("mini_no-image-available.jpg") unless attachment.image.blank? %>
 <% end %>
```

The first part is working fine. But regarding the second part the image from the assets folder is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, I assume you are trying to display **mini** image if image object present for attachment object.

If image object not present in attachment, you are trying to display static image from asset directory.

The code to handle same would be something like this

```
<% item.attachments[0...1].each do |attachment| %>
    <%unless attachment.image.present? %>
        <%= image_tag attachment.image.url(:mini) %>
    <%else%>
        <%= image_tag(asset_path("mini_no-image-available.jpg"))%>
    <%end%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and help @Satishakumar Awati, yes that is exactly what i'm looking for. I tried your code and this is what I get now, all the results that have an image appear with the no image-avalaible and the ones that don't have images don't show any image at all...

Comment: I updated answer can you try again, replaced if with unless